# Name: Where ran code in Intelliji is displayed?

Tags: java

I was pondering about the name of the area where the `System.out.println(“”)`is displayed in Intelliji so I could more effectively express ideas to my coding colleagues

Comment: do you mean ``console``?

Comment: Run or debug window. It actually pops up in the foreground, so you must not have tried to run anything yet.

Comment: google at least you will know it.

Answer (score 0):

> The Run tool window displays output generated by your application. If
> you are running multiple applications, each one is displayed in a tab
> named after the run/debug configuration applied.
>
> If you re-runan application, the new output overwrites the contents of
> the tab. To preserve the output of an application, even if you re-run
> it, pin the output tab.

[image: run tool window]

Press **Ctrl + Shift + F10** key to run your code. Intellij Idea will open **run tool window** to display the output use **Alt + 6** to view the errors  and **Alt + 4** to see the output of your code and press **Esc** key to come to your code window.

Please visit this this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-tool-window.html) of jetbrains.